# Sending a message from Livewire eventDispatch to Alpine.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, tailwind-css, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have a Tailwind alert that uses Livewire and Alpine.js to be displayed when a new project is saved with the event modal-closed

```
<div class="alert alert-success" style="display: none;" x-data="{ show : false }" x-show="show" x-on:close-modal.window="show = true">
    <p class="text-bold text-"><b>The project has been created successfully</b></p>
    <button @click="show = false" class="flex items-center p-1 ml-auto focus:outline-none">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="w-3 h-3 fill-current">
            <path d="M10 8.586L2.929 1.515 1.515 2.929 8.586 10l-7.071 7.071 1.414 1.414L10 11.414l7.071 7.071 1.414-1.414L11.414 10l7.071-7.071-1.414-1.414L10 8.586z">
            </path>
        </svg>
    </button>
</div>
```

And I have a Livewire component that fires a modal-closed event.

```
public function save()
{
    // Validating the data
    $this->validate();

    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('close-modal', ['message' => 'Project Created']);
}
```

What I want is to be able to display the message I'm sending with the `dispatchBrowserEvent` in the alert instead of having a fixed message *"The project has been created successfully."* Unfortunately, I haven't yet figured out how to do this.

I tried to use `x-text="message"` on the `p` tag, but it says

> message is not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to listen for that event with `x-on:close-modal`

```html
<div x-data="{ show : false, message: '' }" 
     x-show="show" 
     x-on:close-modal.window="show = true; message = $event.detail.message">

    <p x-text="message"></p>

</div>
```

*Note: I did what you asked in your question. But I don't think you will see the text as you close the modal and the `p` is inside of it.*

---

If I can suggest an alternative approach is to send a second event

```php
$this->dispatchBrowserEvent('notify', ['message' => 'Project Created']);
```

And have a re-usable toaster to display the notification using the same approach.
*(This is a simplistic example)*

```html
<div x-data="{ show: false, message: '' }" 
     x-show="show" 
     x-on:notify.window="message = $event.detail.message"; setTimeout(() => { message = ''; show = false }, 2500)">

    <p x-text="message"></p>

</div>
```